# SELECT Failed. 3706: Syntax error: expected something between ',' and the end of the request

Tags: sql, vba, teradata

Getting Error code '3706'.  Looks to be something with a comma in my syntax.  Tried to strip the code down as much as possible, yet still getting the error.  My SQL is below.  Using Teradata as well.  Any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT work_order_number, 
sub_type_level_2, 
reporting_region, 
[create_date]+7-Weekday([create_date],7) AS WE, 
create_date

FROM rpt_v_dm_all_work_orders

GROUP BY work_order_number, sub_type_level_2, reporting_region,     
create_date
HAVING (((reporting_region)='Pacific') AND ((create_date) Between Date()-16 And Date()-3));
```

Comment: Please format your code using `{ }`.

Comment: This is no Teradata code, there's no `[..]` and no function named `weekday`. You might use `NEXT_DAY` to find the next weekend...

Answer (score 2):

I've formatted your code and removed some redundant parentheses.

I've added `max()` on a column you don't have in your `GROUP BY` statement as well.

Please try this:

```
SELECT 
    work_order_number, 
    sub_type_level_2, 
    reporting_region, 
    max([create_date]+7-Weekday([create_date],7)) AS WE, 
    create_date 
FROM 
    rpt_v_dm_all_work_orders 
GROUP BY work_order_number, sub_type_level_2, reporting_region, create_date 
HAVING 
    (
    reporting_region = 'Pacific' 
    AND create_date Between Date()-16 And Date()-3 
    );
```

Comment: Why did this answer get downvoted? Please elaborate.